# Request - Response from php server to ruby on rails server. CSRF token issue

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, curl

We are planning interaction between php script to ruby on rails server and  vice-versa.

Whenever I do curl post data from php script, on rails server notification displays - `"Can't verify CSRF token authenticity"`.

I am passing `authenticity_token` in post parameters. We need to how to use this token in secure manner on rails server.

```
<?php

    class active_merchant{    
        private $endpoint_url;      // server address or url where data is to be posted.
        private $params;            // form fields
        private $fields_count;      // count of fields in credit card

        public function __construct(){

            $this->endpoint_url = "http://localhost:8080/activemerchant/index";
            $token = md5('random');
            $this->params = array('name'=>'test','authenticity_token'=>$token);

        }

        /*  function curl_post
            makes a curl post to the end point url
            global variables 
             */

        public function curl_post(){

            try{

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->endpoint_url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($this->params));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
                $response = curl_exec($ch);

                print_r($response);
                //return $response;

            }catch(Exception $e){
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage(),$e->getCode(),$e->gtLine());
            }

        }

    }

    $active_merchant = new active_merchant();
    $active_merchant->curl_post();    
?>
```

Rails code -

```
class ActivemerchantController < ApplicationController
protect_from_forgery except: :index
  def index
    Rails.logger.debug params.inspect
    puts params.inspect
    self.response_body = "Hello, world!"
  end
end
```

Can anyone tell us how can we keep our authenticity_token random ,consistent and secure between two servers (php and ruby on rails).

Comment: I would consider a separate API route that does not use an `authenticity_token` but instead uses some other mechanism to ensure that only authorizied servers are allowed to use that api.

Comment: CSRF token is per request, so if a PHP server did a cURL to get it, it would be the wrong one. Can you temporarily disable CSRF check on Rails app and try

Comment: @Ashish - Yeah disabling CSRF on rails app is working, but that would be not secure as anyone can post data to ruby server on that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If are using the rails controller as an API, protecting with CSRF tokens doesn't make sense. As the name Cross-Site Request Forgery tokens say, they prevent your app from being accessed from anywhere other than the views generated by the same web app.

So, you should disable CSRF in your case and use the authenticity token.

Answering your question with how to securely use this authenticity token on rails app, if you have any user management, assign authenticity tokens to users and find user with a sent token and you know if that user is allowed to make that request. If you don't have a user management, create a database table for authenticity tokens and validate the requests based on what you have in database.

You could write a custom `before_filter` in application_controller and perform the authentication or authorization based on the authenticity_token in the request.

P.S, if you are worried about the authenticity_token being visible for attackers in the network while sending requests, use https.

Answer (score 0):

If Rails app is used as an API server, then simply add `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` in appropriate controller.